# Xcode workspace file is empty

Tags: ios, xcode

My xcode workspace show no files and no editor, previously it was working completely fine and I used it to build my code. Now as workspace is empty I tried to build by using xcodeproj I am getting following error.

"apple mach-o linker error linker command failed with exit code 1"

It will be great to have any ideas to make the Xcode workspace work again.

**From Comment:**

> Initially I made a zip file of my project and uploaded it to google drive. Now I downloaded this file to access my project on a different Mac machine

Comment: can you give some more details it sounds like you xcodeproj file is broken. Did you merge something?

Comment: Initially I made a zip file of my project and uploaded it to google drive. Now I downloaded this file to access my project on a different Mac machine

Comment: Did you try by reinstalling the pods?

Comment: With the information that you give us, we can only guess what is the real problem as TheTiger said pod install should help. Other option can be if xcode don't have rights of the folder that you unzip. Can you show us what you have in the zip file.

Answer (score 7):

> Now as workspace is empty I tried to build by using xcodeproj I am
>   getting following error.

If you are using cocoapods, you should open the **.xcworkspace** file every time.

> Initially I made a zip file of my project and uploaded it to google
>   drive. Now I downloaded this file to access my project on a different
>   Mac machine

Ensure you have zipped it correctly and the project can be opened in the old machine.

Run `pod install` in your directory and open the **.xcworkspace** file again.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is facing this problem after `pod install`, please check below solution:

```
 pod deintegrate 
 pod install
```

This commands remove all Cocoapods dependencies from the project, then add it again.

For me, all the files came back this way.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Cocoa Pods.

Comment: @trojanfoe please see edit. i was facing this issue when i installed pods

Comment: I have same issue and it was problems with pods. deintegrate and install helped me.
Thank you, @dineshsharma